# Need help identifying a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, components

I have a ceramic disc capacitor that got cooked in a power surge due to a faulty generator.    The capacitor was between the fuse and transformer of a circuit board for a pellet stove.

It is RED with and though damaged, I can make out two lines of text

50L10
0933

I believe the first line its a 250volt with 10% tolerance. 
But not sure how to read the 0933  because everything I found on the web talks about 2 and 3 digit codes.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is a capacitor and not an MOV?

Comment: Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: I'm with Steve on this one.  Most likely not a capacitor at all but a MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor).

Comment: Is it in parallel (i.e. across the transformer leads) or in series? (from fuse to one side of transformer)

Comment: CSA mark is a big clue that this device is safety-related, not just a standard capacitor. Although there might be capacitors for medical equipment or something that have that mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added your image.

Appears to be a MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor), whose job is to absorb voltage spikes and surges, which it appears to have done heroically.

You can find a whole family of similar devices [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/circuit-protection/tvs-varistors-movs/655423?k=varistor) - you can choose parameters from the tables to limit the range of types of device, voltages, energy etc.

You'll find that [these](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/Data_Sheets/Littelfuse_MOV_LA.pdf)  look suspiciously similar. From $US0.28 in ones for [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/V150LA2P/F3005-ND/1009260).
These are examples only. Many more.

[image]
Voltage rating wanted depends on whether your system is 110 VAC or 230 VAC or other.

Typical specification table below. You care mainly about continuous AC voltage rating and peak current and/or energy handling. Peak current ratings and Joule energy handling should be as large as you want to afford.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `0933` is probably a date code (33rd week of 2009). I'm not sure about the rest of it though -- I've never seen red capacitors. Could you post a picture?

Comment: wow thanks everyone for the quick responses. Here is the picture  http://www.40er.net/images/IMG_0006.JPG  It is across the AC input power between the fuse and transformer  and the board is labeled VAR1  so I've learned something new.  I always thought that caps were used across input power to smooth it out.